# As3 add Checkbox in Grid component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to add dynamic checkbox in a grid componemt in AS3. [Here](https://engineeringtheworld.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/example.jpg?w=620) is the link. I want to do it in Flash AS3.0 not in Flex.

Comment: Do you mean this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html and this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/CheckBox.html components?

Comment: @Crabar Thank you for your reply. But your answer is not my requirement. Have you seen the link?

Comment: It's not a answer, I am only try to know what not-Flex component you want to use =)

Comment: I am using DataGrid component. I am giving you some snippest. Please check it.

var sampleItem1:Object = { Name:"John Alpha",     Number:"555-123-0101", Email:"jalpha@fictitious.com" };
var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
dg.columns = ["Name","Number","Email"];
dg.addItem(sampleItem1);

Now,
suppose instead of "Number" if I want to add a checkbox ,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For custom cells you need to you use custom cellRenderer on the column.

Main

```
var sampleItem1:Object = {Name:"John Alpha", Number:"555-123-0101", Email:"jalpha@fictitious.com"}; 
var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid(); 
var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Name");
dg.addColumn(dgc);
dgc = new DataGridColumn("Number");
dgc.cellRenderer = "CustomCellRenderer"; // here you set your custom renderer for this column
dg.addColumn(dgc);
dgc = new DataGridColumn("Email");
dg.addColumn(dgc); 
dg.addItem(sampleItem1);
```

CheckBoxCellRenderer.as

```
package 
{ 
    import fl.controls.CheckBox; 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer; 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ListData; 

    public class CustomCellRenderer extends CheckBox implements ICellRenderer { 
        private var _listData:ListData; 
        private var _data:Object; 
        public function CustomCellRenderer() { 
        } 

        public function set data(d:Object):void { 
            _data = d; 
            label = d.label; 
        } 

        public function get data():Object { 
            return _data; 
        } 

        public function set listData(ld:ListData):void { 
            _listData = ld; 
        } 

        public function get listData():ListData { 
            return _listData; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

[source1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd4.html) [source2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#cellRenderer)

Comment: Is it possible to pass some parameters to "CustomCellRenderer"?  Because here in a row there will be 4-5 checkboxs. So I have to distinguish them through ad unique id or something else.

Comment: As I know  there is possible to pass data only through items data. So you can add some fields in item objects and use it in the itemRenderer. Flash engine creates new instance of item renderer for each cell and passes appropriate data.